# extracting text from a column using regexp_substr

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table with a *varchar* column with data like this:

```
"<tasa>
  <parametros>
    <parametro>
      <nombre>ea</nombre>
      <valor>35</valor>
    </parametro>
  </parametros>
  <valorTasa>3.15</valorTasa>
</tasa>"
```

I need to be able to extract the value between the **valorTasa** tags, but don't know how to use the function and can't access oracle documentation.

I'm trying something like

```
select regexp_substr(field, '<valorTasa>[0-9]{0-3}</valorTasa') from dual;
```

With no results.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More simple way would be using [extractvalue](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions061.htm#i1131042) function to extract the value of the node.

```
-- sample of data
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select '<tasa>
  3              <parametros>
  4                <parametro>
  5                  <nombre>ea</nombre>
  6                  <valor>35</valor>
  7                </parametro>
  8             </parametros>
  9             <valorTasa>3.15</valorTasa>
 10           </tasa>'
 11      from dual
 12  )
 13  select extractvalue(xmltype(col), '/tasa/valorTasa') as res
 14    from t1
 15  /

RES
-------
3.15
```

Comment: +1 Nicholas - nice! I plowed ahead with a regex answer and this is a lot slicker :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually `REGEXP_REPLACE` will work best for this. If you put a part of the search expression in parentheses you can refer to it in the third "replace-with" parameter - the first such expression is `\1`, the second is `\2`, and so on up to `\9` (you can't do more than 9).

For your requirement, try this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(myXMLCol, '^.*<valorTasa>(.*)</valorTasa>.*$', '\1') FROM myTable
                                               ^^^^                   ^^
```

The part in the parentheses above - `(.*)` maps to `\1`. The Oracle [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) docs explain this better than I can :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
           regexp_substr(field, '<valorTasa>[0-9\.]+</valorTasa>'), 
           '<valorTasa>([0-9\.]+)</valorTasa>', 
           '\1') 
from dual;
```

Comment: A simple replace would do the trick in this place. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For multiline XML documents, as we have here, **regexp_replace** routine could be used but only with correct match_parameter = **mn** :

```
with t1(col) as(
      select '<tasa>
                <parametros>
                 <parametro>
                   <nombre>ea</nombre>
                    <valor>35</valor>
                  </parametro>
               </parametros>
              <valorTasa>3.15</valorTasa>
            </tasa>'
       from dual
   )
   select 
     REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^.*<valorTasa>(.*)</valorTasa>.*$', '\1', 1, 0, 'mn')  as res
   from t1
/
```